# R version 3.5.1; paquete: readr; read_csv(); Windows 7 Ultimate (Servi Pack 1); falta espacio para ejecutar comando

Tags: r, datatable, data

> R version 3.5.1; paquete: readr; read_csv(); Windows 7 Ultimate (Servi Pack 1); falta espacio para ejecutar comando

2.95 GB de RAM; 33 GB de espacio en Disco Duro.

**Funcion para leer 9,060,698 Rows de un archivo CSV, el archivo .zip pesa 65 MB y el archivo .csv 1.98 GB**

```
ozone <-read_csv("data/hourly_44201_2014.csv", col_types="ccccccinnccccccncnncccccc")

Error in guess_header_(datasource, tokenizer, locale) : 
  Cannot read file C:/Users/Antonio/Documents/data/hourly_44201_2014.csv: Espacio de almacenamiento insuficiente para procesar este comando.
```

Se trata de un ejercicio del libro "Art Of Data Science"
Reinicie la computadora y agregue el parametro n_max con valores 
de: 1.000.000; 100.000; 10.000; 1000; 100; 10 y para cada valor me arroja 
el mismo mensaje.

He modificado la clave de registro IRPStackSize a valores de 11, 1.000, 1.000.000, 19.000.000 sin éxito

Como puedo solucionar esta fallo?

Comment: Si es el archivo que supongo, tiene 65 MB pero es un archivo comprimido, descomprimido son unos 2.1Gb. Acabo de probar importar unos 1000 registros sin problemas. Tengo la teoría que en realidad estás intentando leer directamente el Zip, prueba renombrar `C:/Users/Antonio/Documents/data/hourly_44201_2014.csv` a `*.zip` para poder descomprimir el archivo real.

Comment: Correcto descargue un archivo `.zip`, y al descomprimirlo da un archivo de 1.98 GB, y el archivo esta en el directorio "data", y cuando realice la prueba el archivo estaba descomprimido. También he modificado la clave de registro IRPStackSize con valores (11, 1.000, 1.000.000, 19.000.000) sin éxito (esto en el editor de registro de Windows).

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que el error que mencionas únicamente lo pude reproducir si intento leer directamente el Zip. Leyendo el CSV no he tenido ningún problema.

Comment: Ok, eso me confirma que puede tratarse de un problema de configuración del sistema operativo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se trataba de un **Problema de Recurso del Equipo**, lo comprobé al bajar un **nuevo archivo** que al descomprimirlo da **211 MB**, y al ejecutar las respectivas líneas pude importar los datos.

Debo agradecer a Patricio Moracho por la aclaración de que al descomprimir el **archivo original** (65 MB) resultaba un archivo de **1.98 GB**, cosa que desconocía y no le preste importancia y me guío a saber la causa del problema. Bueno por lo pronto no puedo solucionar el problema de recurso pero tratándose de un ejercicio puedo cambiar los datos con los que voy a trabajar.